# Graph objects for LineGraph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

When I enter for example

```
G = Part[GraphData[10],1];
LG = LineGraph[G];
```

I get error message that `LineGraph` requires a graph object.

How do I convert G into an object accepted by `LineGraph`? I am using version 9 of Mathematica without `Combinatorica` explicitly loaded.  No doubt a very simple question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get at the graph `{"Antiprism",5}` since you get:

```
G = Part[GraphData[10],1]
(* Output: {"Antiprism",5} *)
```

After that, you actually need to use `"LineGraph"` as an argument for `GraphData` as:

```
GraphData[G, "LineGraph"]
```

That should give you the line graph of your `G`.

Answer (score 2):

> *How do I convert `G` into an object accepted by `LineGraph`?*

Wrap it with `GraphData`:

```
G = Part[GraphData[10], 1];

LG = LineGraph[GraphData@G]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]